# RECURSIVE AS для дерева и join с другой таблицей

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Создал рекурсию, которая хорошо работает для вывода пути в иерархии в рамках одной таблицы. Вот запрос

```
 WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
        SELECT 
            p.id,
            p.parent_id,
            p.code,
            p.name as title,
            concat_ws('/', p.name) as pathUrl
        FROM portal.orgunits p
        WHERE p.id = 11

        UNION
        SELECT 
            ou.id,
            ou.parent_id,
            ou.code,
            ou.name,
            concat_ws('/', ou.name, r.pathUrl) as pathUrl
        FROM portal.orgunits ou
                 INNER JOIN r ON ou.id = r.parent_id)
        SELECT r.pathUrl FROM r ORDER BY r.pathUrl DESC LIMIT 1
```

Результат:

`Ledner - Witting/Kunde - Spencer/Bergnaum - Hand`

Но дело в том что у меня есть еще таблица `employees` идентичная c `orunits`(та что в примере приведена). 
В самой таблице `employees` вложеностей не может быть. Вложеность сразу идет на `orunits`
Например мяснай отдел(`orunits`), в нем 1 сотрудник, нужно вывести сотрудника по привязке с parent_id(с мясного отдела - таблица `orunits`). У сотрудников чилдренов нету, они всегда последняя нода.
Мне нужно зайти в `employees` - найти по id сотрудника, подняться наверх к `orunits` и дальше так же продолжить отрисовывать путь. Результат должен быть вот такой: `Ledner - Witting/Kunde - Spencer/Bergnaum - Hand/Chief Books`

Вот как пытаюсь

```
   WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
        SELECT 
            p.id,
            p.parent_id,
            p.code,
            p.name as title,
            concat_ws('/', p.name) as pathUrl
        FROM portal.employees p
        WHERE p.id = 11

        UNION
        SELECT 
            ou.id,
            ou.parent_id,
            ou.code,
            ou.name,
            concat_ws('/', ou.name, r.pathUrl) as pathUrl
        FROM portal.orgunits ou
                 INNER JOIN r ON ou.id = r.parent_id)
        SELECT r.pathUrl FROM r ORDER BY r.pathUrl DESC LIMIT 1
```

просто в первом select заменить `orunits` на `employees` выдает одну строку с имененем самого сотрудника, т.е. рекурсия не продолжает рисовать вверх в `orgunits`
Пытался ставить join но запрос его просто игнорит. Как в запросе начинать рекурсию с одной таблицы и уйти на другую?

Таблица Orgunits

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица Employees (тут фейковые данные, имена фейкером создавались похожие на названия отделов)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В последней таблице parent_id - это id c таблицы orgunits

Comment: limit 1 уберите и посмотрите что у вас вообще в выдаче. и заодно перепроверьте все id. как бы все обязано работать, если не работает - проблема в данных, связь не строиться

Comment: кстати при построении пути "задом наперед", т.е. в строке сначала ребенок, потом родитель ваш первый запрос не может работать корректно, потому что order by с limit первой выдаст скорее всего совершенно не ту запись, которая вам нужна. если выдает ту - значит просто повезло, по алфавиту так подошло. ориентируйтесь на длину пути или введите отдельное поле с порядковым номером итерации